# Show that $\frac{\alpha+y}{\alpha+n+\beta}\in (\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta};\frac{y}{n})$

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-writing, expectation, bayesian

> Suppose you assign a $Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ prior distribution for
>   $\theta$, and the you observed $y$ heads out of $n$ spins. Show
>   algebraically that your posterior mean of $\theta$ always lies between
>   your prior mean $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$ and the observed
>   relative frequency of heads if $\frac{y}{n}$.

I have that $X\sim Bin(n,\theta)$ and $\theta\sim Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ so the posterior is
$$\pi(\theta|x)\propto \pi(\theta)f(x|\theta)= \theta^{\alpha-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta-1}\theta^y(1-\theta)^{n-y}$$
$$=\theta^{a+y-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta+n-y-1}\sim Beta(a+y,n+\beta-y)$$
and the posterior mean is
$$E[\pi(\theta|x)]=\frac{a+y}{a+n+\beta}$$

Now how I show that $$\frac{\alpha+y}{\alpha+n+\beta}\in (\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta};\frac{y}{n})$$
?

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{\alpha+y}{\alpha+n+\beta}=\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha+n+\beta}\cdot\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}+\dfrac{n}{\alpha+n+\beta}\cdot\dfrac{y}{n}$

Take $\gamma=\dfrac{n}{\alpha+n+\beta}\in(0,1)$ then $\dfrac{\alpha+y}{\alpha+n+\beta}=(1-\gamma)\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}+\gamma\dfrac{y}{n}$.

It is a convex combination of $\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$ and $\dfrac{y}{n}$ so lies between the two.

Comment: If a number is combination of both ends, then this number belongs to the range of these extremes ?

Comment: Check that the number is at least the minimum of the two and at most the maximum of the two.

Comment: I edited it to remove the use of a period to represent multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

> **Proposition:** Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive real numbers such that $ad-bc<0$. Then $$\frac{a}{b}<\frac{a+c}{b+d}<\frac{c}{d}$$

First, notice that the requirement is equivalent to $a/b<c/d$, so we can use either as the supposition in the proposition.

$$ad-bc=ad+ac-(ab+bc)<0\Rightarrow\frac{a}{b}<\frac{a+c}{b+d}$$ by dividing both sides by $b(b+d)$. Likewise

$$ac-bd=cd+ac-(cd+bd)<0\Rightarrow\frac{a+c}{b+d}<\frac{b}{d}$$ by dividing both sides by $d(b+d)$.

---

This proposition is actually hugely useful in combinatorics, as you can use it to prove that the probability that an event occurs is strictly between $0$ and $1$ if and only if it can both occur and not occur. We use this principle in combinatorics to probabilistically prove that graphs have certain properties by showing the probability a randomly created large graph has the property is non-zero

Answer (score 0):

In situations like these when you know that a double-sided inequality holds in advance and are only asked to prove it, you can reverse-engineer a proof using the idea of the weighted average, about which we know that it must lie strictly between the values averaged, provided that all weights are non-zero.

In your particular case, take $w_1 = \alpha + \beta$, $w_2 = n$. Then

$$
\frac{\alpha + y}{\alpha + \beta + n} = \frac{w_1\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} + w_2\frac{y}{n}}{w_1 + w_2}
$$

This approach will always work, and in case of simple rational functions of several variables will involve only solving a system of linear equations.